# How to load a ScrollView from the bottom

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

I have the following `ScrollView`. I would like it to initially load content from the bottom, showing the last elements first so that you first scroll from bottom upwards :

```
<ScrollView
  vertical
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
  {chatMsgs.map(ChatMsg => (
    <ChatMsg key={Math.random()} />
  ))}
</ScrollView>
```

How can I go about implementing this scenario?

I have tried `display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-end',` but to no success. I did not expect it to work anyway.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contentOffset` props and set arbitrary `y` value.

```
 <ScrollView
  vertical
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentOffset={{x: 0, y: 9999}} />
  ))}>
  {chatMsgs.map(ChatMsg => (
    <ChatMsg key={Math.random()} />
  ))}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mina. Works great. Did a little edit though.

Comment: You are weclome.